# Integrate an index of a for-loop into path of a function inside the loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, keras

I want to predict if an image is a technical drawing or not. I created an CNN with keras in python which works fine for single picture prediction. Now I want to predict more than one picture per run. So I thought about creating a loop to solve this problem. The point I seem to miss here is how I implement the index of the loop to a path. So each loop the next image in the folder (named from 1-47) will be picked and predicted. I thought replacing the filename with the index should be enough but it seems that the index variable has no access to the path itself?

Here is my loop :

```py
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
prediction=list(range(50)) #Create an empty list of 50 entrys
for  i in enumerate(47,start=1): 
    test_image = image.load_img('C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Predict/i.jpg', target_size = (64, 64),color_mode = 'grayscale') #Defines your single image you want to predict. This image has to be unseen by the network before. So it is necessary to withdraw those files from the whole data set before running the code. 
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = classifier.predict(test_image)
    training_set.class_indices
    if result[0][0] == 1:
        prediction[i] = 'Tech. draw.'
    else:
        prediction[i] = 'No tech. draw.'

print(prediction)
```

Comment: `enumerate` takes an iterable, such as `range(47)`.  In newer Python versions you can use an `f` string creator:  `f'C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Predict/{i}.jpg'`.  Practice this sort of enumeration in an interactive Python session.  It's easier to debug small code pieces interactively.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are called `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`..., you should change the name of the file you are reading. Now it is reading the file `i.jpg`.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
prediction=list(range(50)) #Create an empty list of 50 entrys
for  i in enumerate(47,start=1): 
    ## here, replace your `i.jpg` by the current value of i
    test_image = image.load_img('C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Predict/'+str(i)+'.jpg', target_size = (64, 64),color_mode = 'grayscale') #Defines your single image you want to predict. This image has to be unseen by the network before. So it is necessary to withdraw those files from the whole data set before running the code. 
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = classifier.predict(test_image)
    training_set.class_indices
    if result[0][0] == 1:
        prediction[i] = 'Tech. draw.'
    else:
        prediction[i] = 'No tech. draw.'

print(prediction)
```